# Type error: Argument 2 passed to with() must be callable or null, object given

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections

```
Route::get('/',function (){
    $collection = collect(['product'=>'chair','price'=>100]);    
    //dd($collection);
    return view('welcome')-with('prices',$collection);
});
```

I want to pass $collection on view but I get this error:

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to with() must be callable or null,
>
> object given

and I don't understand why.

Can somebody explain me?

Comment: There seems to be a typo, forgot the arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $page_data = array(
      'product'=>'chair',
      'price'=>100
    );
return \View::make('welcome', $page_data);
or
return view('welcome', $page_data);
```

Comment: Undefined variable: page_data when i try to send

Comment: $page_data = array(
        'product'=>'chair',
        'price'=>100
    );
 return view('welcome', $page_data);

Comment: Put dd($page_data) and check

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "product" => "chair"
  "price" => 100
]

Comment: but when i what to iterate

Comment: sorry for spam,@foreach($page_data as $item)
   {{$item}}
   @endforeach then show me error Undefined variable: page_data

Comment: Just do this in your view {{product}}

Answer (score 6):

Use `->with` instead of `-with`:

```
return view('welcome')->with('prices',$collection);
```

Comment: Please style the code and add the small code description about your code.